# Generating SSH key with ssh-keygen produces 'File name too long' error

Tags: ssh

I tried to generate a new SSH key in Gitbash using

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "me@myaccount.com"
```

I got prompted to `Enter file in which to save the key` and as the default path didn't work I substituted my own path: `/c/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa`

However, I just get an error: `failed: File name too long`.

Would anyone know what I could do to get this to work?

Comment: There is a 260 character limit for file paths on NTFS. This can be removed [via policy in Windows 10](https://mspoweruser.com/ntfs-260-character-windows-10/). Are either of the fully qualified paths, including symlinks, over 260 characters?

Comment: I definetly don't think I went over 260 chars. I just used the path above `/c/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa`